# Can the custom user claims be updated through the Firebase REST API?

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have to update the user claims and I prefer to do this with php. Updating "displayName" or other information works just fine, but when I try to send custom attributes in the request body, I got an "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION" error. Is this operation not possible or it's just my code?

The PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty'.
    '/setAccountInfo?key=[API_KEY]'
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ],
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => \json_encode([
        'idToken' => [FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN],
        'customAttributes' => \json_encode([
             'admin' => true
         ]),
    ]),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

And the full error returned in response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION"
 }
}
```

I've had tested replacing the 'customAttributes' with 'customClaims' and not encoding the claims, with no success. All performed under https connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update custom claims for a user the user credentials provided through an ID Token are not enough - a user is not allowed to set their own custom claims (which are considered administrative properties, not user editable properties).

To be able to set custom claims, you need to authenticate the requests with Service Account Credentials. This and other administrative tasks are provided by one of the Firebase Admin SDKs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin).

Unfortunately, Google doesn't provide an official Admin SDK for PHP - but fortunately, there is an unofficial one that you can find at https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php (Disclaimer: I'm the author :))